# Can't send transactional e-mail in magento custom module

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7, email-templates

I can't send mail using my custom email template.

My etc/config file code

```
<template>
      <email>
           <quickrfq_email_enquiryadmintemplate translate="label" module="quickrfq">
                <label>Admin Enquiry Form</label>
                  <file>enquiryadmin.html</file>
                  <type>html</type>
           </quickrfq_email_enquiryadmintemplate>
    </email>
</template>
```

My controller code to send mail

```
           $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT))
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,              
                   null
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
```

But i m getting error `There has been an error processing your request`

Comment: What is the error mentioned in var/log ?

Comment: exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customcontacts')->__('Thanks for your enquiry. We will be in touch shortly!'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
```

Comment: it alway run to fail send email success

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code to below:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('quickrfq_email_enquiryadmintemplate');

            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT))
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,              
                   null
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
```